# how to use sorted with key of bool in python?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I have list contains digits.
my target is to move all of the zeros to the end while preserving the order of the other elements.
this algorithm- `sorted(array, key=lambda x:x==0)` works well.
to my comprehesion when the key equals to True the sorted function moves the digit to the end of the list. may you explain me why?

e.g [1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3] # returns [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0]

Comment: Which part is confusing you?

Answer (score 3):

`False == 0` and `True == 1` which makes `False < True` just as `0 < 1`. So the keys of your list are sorted in ascending order:

```
[False, False, False, False, False, True, True]
```

Comment: You might want to mention that Timsort is stable